# Re-evaluate quality gate in Sonarqube without a new analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Is there any way to tell Sonarqube to check again if a project passes a quality gate without starting a new analysis?

Currently, whenever I change the metrics of a quality gate, I would run a new analysis (obviously with the same result, as there are no code changes) for every project using that gate to get updated information whether it passes with the new requirements.

I hope there is an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quality gate compliance is calculated as part of the analysis. No way around that.